# Twig doesn't show static images

Tags: html, css, twig

I started learning Slim Framework and I'm now building a web app.

My problem is that when I use the `<img>` tag my images are not shown. I am using the **Picnic CSS** library.

```
<img src="asd.png" class="logo">
```

Comment: Is your image at the correct location? So that src="asd.png" is correct?
If so could you provide more information about your folder structure and a more specific example?

Comment: Surely not a `twig` problem here - Try using an absolute `URL`